# Dynamic Meta Description

Tags: search, coldfusion, meta

I have a page which populates meta keywords and meta description dynamically for a bunch of products. Now that I think back on it, can search engines even see that meta data when they crawl since it isn't even rendered on the page until runtime? Does meta need to be hard-coded to allow search engines to see it?

Answer (score 3):

When the search engine analyses the page, it just requests it like anyone else would.  "Runtime" in a CF sense occurs before the page is served:

1. The user agent (be that a browser or a search engine crawler) sends a request to the web server
2. The web server passes it to CF
3. CF renders request and creates the HTML doc (incl. all your metadata)
4. CF passes it back to the web server
5. The web server sends the response sent back to user agent

So, yes, it sees your metadata.